Movie with a scene where ugly girl looks pretty based on people she's with?
All I recall is this one scene; one guy is chilling with his buddies at this bar.  They're scoping out this blonde chick.  One guy says, "She's not that hot."  The other guys dispute it.  So the guy makes a frame with his thumbs and forefingers and you see the girl through the frame.  And he's like, "Now she's hot."  And he moves his frame out a bit to include the girls around her, and suddenly she has buck teeth and her hair isn't as pretty.  And he repeats this process, and then the guys all agree she's not that pretty.
It's a recent movie, probably within the past few years.  Major Hollywood release, comedy, with at least one big(ger) name star, but I can't remember who.

Found it.  It's Hall Pass (2011).  Thanks to dbugger who made me use the word "morph" when describing it.  :)




I remember that scene -- good find.
